# Restore specific items using Titanium Backup without root?

Tags: restore

I regularly backup my entire phone using Titanium Backup.

For the next two weeks or so, im going to be using my friends phone. Id like to restore a few things from the backup (contacts, some app data etc.) without rooting it. Is there any way?

Comment: You can normally unroot yes, but that's a separate question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Titanium stores the .apk's in `/sdcard/TitaniumBackup/` and the data in the same folder in zip files.  You can click the .apk to install it when viewing in a file manager.

To restore the data, you can extract the zip file on a PC and copy the contents of the `data` folder (another folder named something like `com.domain.appname`) to `/data/data/` on the device using adb:

`adb push com.domain.appname /data/data/`

Comment: You just see me double-confused: OP asked *without rooting* -- so how to access `/data/data` then? And since when is `/data/data` read-only -- how should apps store their data then? Another point to take care with this method: for system stuff (here: contacts) a simple copy might break things if the ROMs/Android versions of the two devices differ. Not only hear-say, but my own sad experience ;)

Comment: @Izzy ADB should have access to `/data/data` without rooting; that's how [Carbon](http://www.clockworkmod.com/carbon) works.  As for the read-only bit I was apparently thinking of the system partition? :P

Comment: 1) look at the date -- no Carbon then (and Android 4.0 was released only 10/2011). 2) No, that's not how Carbon works. Carbon does not *copy*, but is simply a frond-end to `adb backup` and `adb restore` (I can give you more details in chat if you want). 3) yes, for r/o you most likely had `/system` in mind :)

Comment: So peeps, I'm also interested in backing up and MOST IMPORTANTLY RESTORING application data, can this carbon/adb do that on a NON-ROOTED device? A new tablet with warranty on 4.2.2. Just a simple answer with a pinch of hint, thank you.

Comment: @emm980 It's called [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) now and yes, the entire point is to backup & restore apps and data without root.

Comment: What if the backup was done in TitaniumBackup? How can I restore it on an unrooted phone?